# Wordpress upload attachments to root

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I want to upload a PDF file so I can have an URL like this:

```
 http://www.mydomain.com/attachment.pdf
```

But how can I achieve this? Because when I upload the file via Media in de wordpress administration panel it has an URL like this:

```
 http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/attachment.pdf
```

But I don't need the "wp-content/uploads" stuff in my URL.

I also tried to upload the file with an Ftp upload on to the root but when I want to go to that URL it says "page not found"

any ideas?

Comment: You will have to change using wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

You change the upload location by adding following line in your `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'UPLOADS', '/blog/wp-content/uploads' );
```

By adding this line the image url would be somewhat like this

```
http://localhost/wordpress/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/btn2.png/btn3.png
```

If you try and remove the `blog/content/uploads` then also the year and date remains

For that Go to Settings and media and uncheck the organsize media option..

Hope it works for you ..

**Note: This Steps are not for beginners. Use it only if you know what you are doing.**

Comment: It almost works, but now I have www.mydomain.com//attachment.pdf. It has 2 slashes instead one, any fix for that? :)

Comment: Have a look at this .. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/ I have nt tried ..

Answer (score 0):

Please check below url for change path of wordpress upload

[To change File/Image Upload Path in WordPress](http://www.creativedev.in/2013/07/to-change-fileimage-upload-path-in-wordpress/)

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting your WordPress site on a machine you can [SSH](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/command/) into:

1. You can verify the file you uploaded through FTP is in the right place (and move it to the right place if it's not)
2. You can move the file uploaded through WordPress to the right place

To be available at http://www.example.com/attachment.pdf the file has to be in the same directory as the index.php file, wp-settings.php file, wp-admin folder, etc.

You can log into the remote machine with SSH and use [Bash commands](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/command-line-commands) (especially `ls` and `mv`) to view and move files.